# How do we import some function from a file instead of importing whole file in NextJs/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, next.js

So, for example let's say we have two files: 
File A -

```
export const a = () => {}
export const b = () => {}
```

Now, importing this in File B -

```
import { a } from 'path'
```

So when I run `npm run analyze`, it told me I am importing whole file A in file B.
I want to reduce import cost, so is there any way that I can only import specific function from a file.

Comment: try using `module.exports.a=()=>{}`

Comment: Its es5 syntax. What I'd written is in es6.

Answer (score 0):

This is what usually tools like Webpack or Rollup do.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: I think webpack is inbuilt in next js, so Is there any workaround here?